# How to use a DocumentDB(MongoDB) connection string as an Environment variable in an Azure Resource Management Template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

I want to use a DocumentDB(MongoDB) connection string as an environment variable in an Azure Resource Management Template. Forexample i have a resource group which has a wep app and a DocumentDB(MongoDB) database.

```
"siteConfig": {
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "db",
              "value": "connection string"
            }
          ]
        }
```

How can i assign an environment variable to a connection string in template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARM template supports `listKeys` and `list{Value}` function, more details we can refer to [ARM template function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions#listkeys).
We can find DocumentDB [list connection strings API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdbresourceprovider/databaseaccounts#DatabaseAccounts_ListConnectionStrings), so we can use listconnectionstrings function to get documentdb connection string in the ARM template.

```
"appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "db",
              "value": " [listConnectionStrings(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts', parameters('documentdb')), '2015-04-08').connectionStrings[0].connectionString]"
            }
```

It works correct on my side. If we want to add appsetting for WebApp, we also can do with following code

```
  "resources": [
      {
          "name": "appsettings",
          "type": "config",
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "dependsOn": [
              "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('webSiteName'))]"
          ],
          "tags": {
              "displayName": "appsetting"
          },
        "properties": {
          "db": "[listConnectionStrings(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts', parameters('documentdb')), '2015-04-08').connectionStrings[0].connectionString]"
        }
      }

  ]
```

[image]

Check the result from the Azure portal.

[image]

**Update:**

ARM template demo code

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "hostingPlanName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "documentdb": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "skuName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "S1",
      "allowedValues": [
        "F1",
        "D1",
        "B1",
        "B2",
        "B3",
        "S1",
        "S2",
        "S3",
        "P1",
        "P2",
        "P3",
        "P4"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's pricing tier and instance size. Check details at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/"
      }
    },
    "skuCapacity": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 1,
      "minValue": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's instance count"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "webSiteName": "[concat('webSite', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
    "docDbName": "tomdocumentdb",
    "storageAccountId": "[concat(resourceGroup().id,'/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "HostingPlan"
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('skuName')]",
        "capacity": "[parameters('skuCapacity')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "Website"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      },

      "resources": [
          {
              "name": "appsettings",
              "type": "config",
              "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
              "dependsOn": [
                  "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('webSiteName'))]"
              ],
              "tags": {
                  "displayName": "appsetting"
              },
            "properties": {
              "db": "[listConnectionStrings(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts', parameters('documentdb')), '2015-04-08').connectionStrings[0].connectionString]"
            }
          }

      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Paramter file

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "hostingPlanName": {
            "value": "tomtest" //your hostingplan name
        },
        "skuName": {
            "value": "B1"
        },
        "documentdb": {
            "value": "tomdocument" // your documentdb name
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Tom Sun, if i define the connection string in properties it gives this error Deployment template validation failed: 'The template parameter documentdb' is not found. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#parameters for usage details.'. (Code: InvalidTemplate) And if i in appsettings define, then it does not give any value but the reference code [listConnectionStrings(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts', parameters('documentdb')), '2015-04-08').connectionStrings[0].connectionString]

Comment: we need to define the paramter  `documentdb` in the template. `documentdb` is the name of  documentdb(MongoDB). You also can get the define from the screenshot in the parameter section.

Comment: yeah i tried with his name in properties, but it didn't accept too, now i'm testing with appSettings

Comment: It didn't work, in my template parameter is defined like: "databaseAccounts_feedsdb_name_1": {
      "defaultValue": "feedsdb",
      "type": "String"
    }, i don't know what i do wrong

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of a struggle:

```
"appSettings": [{
                    "Name": "DOCUMENTDB_ENDPOINT",
                    "Value": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/', parameters('databaseAccountName'))).documentEndpoint]"
                }, {
                    "Name": "DOCUMENTDB_PRIMARY_KEY",
                    "Value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts', parameters('databaseAccountName')), '2015-04-08').primaryMasterKey]"
                }]
```

Comment: Hey @4c74356b41 it is a MongoDB connection string.

Comment: Yes :) thanx but they are different and it gives error.

Comment: well, this gives are an answer from which you can easily create your own, I have no idea how mongodb connection string looks, but this gives you all you need to create that, I'm pretty sure @LeventOner

Comment: I dont want to take your time but i really can't find, in MongoDB i should define only the password. var url = 'mongodb://<emailList>:<password>@<emailList>.documents.azure.com:10250/?ssl=true';